# How to do Previous and Next item on a List<G>

Tags: asp.net, list

I have a class called Person, which contains various properties such as first name, last name, etc.

I have a List that contains n instances of Person.

```
List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();
```

What I need to be able to do is search lstPerson for a given person, and having found that person then obtain the previous and next person relative to the person's item position in lstPerson.

```
Person p = lstPerson.Find(delegate(Person o) { return o.FirstName == "Joe"; });

// Then use an accessor to get the previous and next persons
Person prevPerson = p.Previous();
Person nextPerson = p.Next();
```

**Is there a better way to do this then the one that I stated above?** What I don't like about the above solution is that I have to construct the previous and next pointers at the time that I build the Person List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
int personIndex = lstPerson.FindIndex(delegate(Person o) { return o.FirstName == "Joe" });
Person p = lstPerson[personIndex];
// verify that personIndex+1 and personIndex-1 still fall within the list
Person prevPerson = lstPerson[personIndex-1];
Person nextPerson = lstPerson[personIndex+1];
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! I'm ashamed to admit that I didn't even know the FindIndex() method was there, which I should have known because I use Find() and FindAll() quite frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. why not simply using the [LinkedList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)?
It comes with Next and Previous built in.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, which skips elements until the next element matches or it has gone through the entire list:

```
var list = (new List<Person>() { null }).Concat(lstPerson);
var p = list.SkipWhile((x, index) => { var n = list.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1); return n == null || n.FirstName != name; }).Take(3);

Person previous = p.FirstOrDefault();
Person person = p.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
Person next = p.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```

Although this (similar to @marcind's answer) might be clearer:

```
Person person = lstPerson.Find(p => p.FirstName == name);
Person previous = null;
Person next = null;

if (person != null)
{
    int index = lstPerson.IndexOf(person);
    previous = lstPerson.ElementAtOrDefault(index - 1);
    next = lstPerson.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1);
}
```